# Ist "Borschtsch" ein einsilbiges Wort?

Tags: pronunciation

In einen Sketch zweier österreichischer Kabarettisten, wird das längste einsilbige, deutsche Wort gesucht. Die Lösung wird mit Borschtsch (der traditionelle russische Eintopf) gefunden. Als Zugabe, wird der zweite Fall dieses Wortes genannt: "des Borschtschs".
Die Tatsache, dass Borschtsch aus dem Russischen kommt, wird nicht weiter diskutiert.

Meine Frage: ist Borschtsch ein einsilbiges Wort?

Die dahinter stehende Frage: Was definiert eine Silbe?
Man könnte Borschtsch einsilbig aussprechen, oder zweisilbig: Borsch-tsch.

Comment: -1: Wo hast du nachgeschaut, was eine Silbe bedeutet, und was davon hast du nicht verstanden?

Comment: Im Borschtsch ist schon genug Zeugs drin, da muss man nicht auch noch einen Trennstrich reintun...

Comment: @tofro: Und auch keine weiteren Silben.

Comment: Was macht "Borsch-tsch" zweisilbig?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Jedenfalls ist in der kyrillischen Schrift der Konsonantencluster *schtsch* ein einzelner Buchstabe: [Щ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A9). Das spricht schon mal dafür, das Wort als einsilbig zu betrachten. Das hat aber für die Aussprache im Deutschen wenig Gewicht.

Gewichtiger ist hingegen folgende Überlegung:

Eine gesprochene Silbe hat einen Silbenkern (auch Silbengipfel genannt), der entweder ein Vokal (Monophthong oder Diphthong) oder ein vokalisierter Konsonant ist (z.B. das R im Namen der kroatischen Insel *K**r**k* oder das l in *Dirnd**l***). Vokalisiert können aber nur sonore, also klingende Konsonanten werden, das sind:

- [l] (**L**icht)
- [r] (**R**ad)
- [n] (**N**ase)
- [m] (**M**aus)
- [ŋ] (Go**ng**)

Frikative wie [ʃ] (**Sch**uh) oder gar Plosive wie [t] (**T**isch) kommen als Silbenkern nicht in Frage. Damit gibt es nur zwei Kandidaten für einen Silbenkern, nämlich o und r, wobei aber das r ausscheidet, weil es direkt neben einem Vokal steht. Damit gibt es nur einen einzigen Silbenkern, und damit auch nur eine Silbe.

---

**phonetische Silbenaufteilung**

Man teil jedem gesprochenen Laut einen Sonoritätswert zu. Dabei gelten diese Werte:

- Plosive (p, b, t, d, k, g und der Glottisschlag<sup>*</sup>): 1
- Frikative (s, sch, f, w, ch, h): 2
- Nasale (n, m, ng wie in si**ng**en oder Go**ng**): 3
- Liquida (r, l): 4
- Approximanten (Viele Vokale, aber auch j): 5
- geschlossene Vokale: 6
- offene Vokale: 7

<sup>Der Glottisschlag ist der Knacklaut vor dem A in Apfel, bzw. zwischen E und A in *beachten*, er ist zwar ein ganz gewöhnlicher Konsonant, wird aber in der Schrift nie durch einen eigenen Buchstaben wiedergegeben.</sup>

Im Fall von [bɔʁʃtʃ] ergibt sich dadurch die Folge 174212

Die Silbengipfel sind in so einer Folge die lokalen Maxima, und die Grenzen dazwischen sind die Minima. Nun gibt es hier ein Minimum, das nicht an einer Wortgrenze liegt, nämlich beim vorletzten Laut, und das legt nahe, dass es dort eine Silbengrenze geben sollte.

Diese Minimum-Regel hat aber eine Ausnahme. Sie gilt nämlich genau dann nicht, wenn dadurch eine Silbe entstünde, die keinen sonoren Laut enthält, und die potentielle Silbe [tʃ] ist so ein Konsonantencluster, der nur Laute mit sehr kleinen Sonoritäten enthält.

Ähnliche Beispiele sind z.B. *des Tests* oder *des Palasts*, zu denen die Zahlenfolgen 17212 und 1747212 gehören, und bei denen die letzten zwei Laute [ts] ebenfalls keine eigene Silbe bilden. Diese Ausnahmen treten auch am Beginn von Wörtern auf, nämlich z.B immer dann, wenn ein Wort mit »st« beginnt (z.B »stumm« = 2163). Es gibt sogar einsilbige Wörter, bei denen diese Ausnahme vorne und hinten auftritt (»Strumpf« = 2146312).

Daher:

**»Borschtsch« ist ein einsilbiges Wort.**

---

**Zusatz** (gehört nicht zur eigentlichen Antwort):

Ein [Gschnas](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gschnas) ist in Österreich ein Fest, bei dem man verkleidet erscheint, das ist vor allem im Fasching der Fall. Es spricht nichts dagegen, ein Gschnas unter ein bestimmtes Motto zu stellen, und wenn man als Motto die rote russische Suppe wählt, hat man ein ...

> Borschtschgschnas

Ich gebe zu, dieses Kompositum ist ziemlich an den Haaren herbeigezogen, aber darin kommt die längste durchgehende Konsonantenfolge vor, die man in einem deutschen Wort finden kann:

> rschtschgschn

Das sind 13 Konsonantbuchstaben (7 Konsonantlaute) in Folge.

Comment: Sehr typisch für Sprachen wie das Deutsche (und viele andere indogermanische Sprachen) sind auch Wörter wie *Stein,* die im Silbenlaut eine kleine Umkehrung in der Sonoritätshierarchie aufweisen («Stein» = 21753).

Comment: Die Deutsche Transkription ist etwas irreführend, m.M.n. Ein "T" zwischen den zwei Frikativen lässt sich im Russischen kaum hören. "Sch-ch" wäre eine bessere Approximation.

Comment: @Beta Bei Sch-ch wäre der deutschsprachige Russischlerner vermutlich verwirrt, weil nicht eindeutig ist, welches _ch_ gemeinst ist, das aus _ich_ oder _ach_ :)

Answer (score 6):

Wie in der Frage schon erwähnt wird, kommt Borschtsch aus dem Russischen; diese Schreibweise ist eine Transliteration des Wortes **борщ**. Da es zu dem letzten Buchstaben darin, dem Konsonanten ***щ***, keine deutsche Entsprechung gibt, macht man die Transliteration mit "schtsch", was die Ausprache approximiert. Was Silben angeht, ist das Russische - auch eine indoeuropäische Sprache - analog zum Deutschen. **Борщ** ist russisch einsilbig, also auch auf Deutsch.