# Was ist das längste untrennbare Wort der deutschen Sprache?

Tags: single-word-request, hyphenation

Ich bin gerade über das Wort *Schrift* gestolpert: ein völlig normales, häufig gebrauchtes deutsches Wort.
Mit der kleinen Besonderheit, dass es mir in LaTeX eine Zeile zerschossen hat.
Es ist nämlich nicht trennbar.

Da kam mir die Frage nach dem längsten untrennbaren deutschen Wort.
Erstaunlicherweise konnte ich das mit einer einfachen Googlesuche nicht herausfinden, und noch erstaunlicher ist, dass hier noch niemand nachgefragt zu haben scheint.

Deshalb die Frage: Was ist das längste deutsche Wort, das sich nicht trennen lässt?

Comment: "*Schrank*" ist zwar genau so lang, die Buchstaben "ank" sind jedoch i.d.R. breiter als die Buchstaben "ift".

Comment: Auf "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/de.etc.sprache.deutsch/vAfGRb-2mOc" gibt es einige Beispiele mit 10 Buchstaben; außerdem wird der Genitiv einer russischen Suppe (11 Buchstaben) und der Genitiv eines osteuropäischen Familiennamens (12 Buchstaben) genannt.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Der Link ist ungültig, könntest du ihn korrigieren?

Comment: *Der Geschmack des Borschtschs*

Comment: Unter "längste einsilbige" habe ich wiedergefunden, worauf auch Tofro vielleicht hinweisen will, ohne es als Duplikat zu verlinken https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/42038/ist-borschtsch-ein-einsilbiges-wort

Comment: @Philipp Entschuldigung. Hier nochmal der Link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwji_oaEqubaAhXBDZoKHcjkC00QFjAAegQIABAr&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fd%2Ftopic%2Fde.etc.sprache.deutsch%2FvFOy63M_qB8&usg=AOvVaw2cnT_ow2xM7A0TiIp3_urR

Comment: @MartinRosenau Danke. Schleichst, schrumpfst und schlauchst, und ganz besonders muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuh sind gute Beispiele. Ich habe boršč als Fremdwort betrachtet und nicht Borschtsch geschrieben, aber wenn der Duden das sagt, wird es stimmen… Sicher auch eine Frage der Transkription.

Comment: Ich würde gerne "Schlauch" hinzufügen. 8 Buchstaben, eine Silbe, nicht trennbar (meines Wissens).

Comment: Noch ein Kandidat: der Schlumpf